# Jquerymobile - $.mobile.changepage - issues

Tags: jquery

I am using the $.mobile.changePage function for move one page to another in Jquerymobile. But I am getting the double transition while moving the between page.
I dont know why it happened ?

If any one have same problem Please let me know how to solve this one. 
I am using the jquerymobile alpha 3

THanks in advance

Comment: Provide some code to dive into

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Script tag inside the page that you are firing the $.mobile.ChangePage from?

If so, you need to move it to an outside js file and load it in the header.  otherwise, everytime the div loads, it'll double add the script to the dom, and you'll get multiple firings.